# Given four real numbers $a_1<a_2<a_3<a_4$, rearrange them in such an order $a_{i_1}$, $a_{i_2}$, $a_{i_3}$, $a_{i_4}$ that the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Given four real numbers $a_1 \lt a_2 \lt a_3 \lt a_4$, rearrange them in such an order
$a_{i_1}
, a_{i_2}
, a_{i_3}
, a_{i_4} $
that the sum

$$S = (a_{i_1}-a_{i_2})^2 + (a_{i_2}-a_{i_3})^2 + (a_{i_3}-a_{i_4})^2 + (a_{i_4}-a_{i_1})^2$$ has the least possible value?
Can you generalise for $n$ real numbers?

---

I opened up the equation but it was not of much use.

We can observe that the $3$ inequalities hold:

1) $a_4-a_1 \gt a_3-a_1 \gt a_2-a_1 $
2) $a_4-a_1 \gt a_4-a_2 \gt a_4-a_3 $ .
3) $a_4-a_2 \gt a_3-a_2$

And I believe the order giving the smallest $S$ will be given by $ a_4, a_2, a_1, a_3 $ which is equivalent to the sum if the order is  $ a_4, a_3, a_1, a_2 $,

so

$$S = (a_{i_4}-a_{i_2})^2 + (a_{i_2}-a_{i_1})^2 + (a_{i_1}-a_{i_3})^2 + (a_{i_3}-a_{i_4})^2$$

and

$$S = (a_{i_4}-a_{i_3})^2 + (a_{i_3}-a_{i_1})^2 + (a_{i_1}-a_{i_2})^2 + (a_{i_2}-a_{i_4})^2$$

Although I am not sure on how to prove this, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $f(a,c,b,d) > f(a,b,c,d) > f(a,b,d,c).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588116/prove-that-fa-c-b-d-fa-b-c-d-fa-b-d-c)

Comment: Just adding that the above link indeed contains all rearrangements one needs to consider. In general, there are $4! = 24$ rearrangements of these numbers, but firstly since $abcd$ yields the same sum as the cyclic permutations $bcda,cdab,dabc$, for every rearrangement there are four redundant ones, so 24/4 = 6 rearrangements up to these cyclic ones. But additionally, for every arrangement $abcd$ the reverse arrangement $dcba$ also yields the same sum, so perform another division 6/2 = 3. So the above three options $acbd, abcd, abdc$ are the only ones one needs to care about.